# PyQt open a subwindow with table (turing machine App)

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

I would like to create a window with a button `"ruban"` and when I click on this button it open a new window with a table containing the `"data"`. 
My problem is when i run it, and i click on the button it doesn't appear anything....

Thanks a lot for any help !

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

data = {'col1':['1','2','3'], 'col2':['4','5','6'], 'col3':['7','8','9']}

class Window (QtGui.QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):
      super(Window, self).__init__()
      self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
      self.setWindowTitle("Machine de Turing")
      #self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))

      self.home()

   def home(self):

      btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Ruban", self)
      btn1.clicked.connect(self.edit_ruban)
      btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())

      self.show()


   def edit_ruban(self):

      table = MyTable(self, data, 5, 3)
      table.show()


class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = data
        self.setmydata()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def setmydata(self):

        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)



def run():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   GUI=Window()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong  arguments in call to  `MyTable.__init__`.
It's not clear why you add `self` as the first arg. 
Python provides implicit `self` so it's `data` that must go first.
If you intended to provide parent window for MyTable it must go last,
see the signature `QTableWidget::QTableWidget ( int rows, int columns, QWidget * parent = 0 )`,
so the call would loo like this:

```
table = MyTable(data, 5, 3, self)
```

But `MyTable` by default will be emdedded  into `Window` Apparently that's not you want.
To avoid embedding either omit `parent` argument and save a reference to the newly created table

```
def edit_ruban(self):
  table = MyTable(data, 5, 3) # no parent provided
  table.show()
  self.table = table # this prevents the garbage collector
                     # from deleting the new table
```

or better set window flags to `Qt.Window`

```
def edit_ruban(self):
  table = MyTable(data, 5, 3, self)
  # add Qt.Window to table's flags 
  table.setWindowFlags(table.windowFlags() | Qt.Window)
  table.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work fine but in the second way with     'Qt.window'  I do not understand why it work...

Comment: @Dadep It's like QDialog, it has this flag set. All non-embedded qt windows have this flag. Hence to make a widget a window with frame, close buttons add this flag to window flags. See [qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum).